# In Clojure macros how to force auto names to be identical?

Tags: clojure

I'm writing some Clojure macros that I want to use on top of enlive-html macros. Now I need to write a macro which, when used like this:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(def-app
  [ [:page/not-found [{path :path}]
      [:path] (content path)]

    [:page/other-page [{x :x}]
      [:x] (content x)]]))
```

...would expand to this:

```
(def app ^:dynamic {})

(def-page app
  [:page/not-found [{path :path}]
    [:path] (content path)])

(def-page app
  [:page/other-page [{x :x}]
    [:x] (content x)])
```

My attempt is this:

```
(defmacro def-app [pages]
  `(do
    (def app# ^:dynamic {})

    ~@(for [page# pages]
      `(def-page app# ~page#))))
```

...which expands to this:

```
(do (def app__3251__auto__ {}) 
    (user/def-page app__3250__auto__ [:page/not-found [{path :path}] [:path] (content path)]) 
    (user/def-page app__3250__auto__ [:page/other-page [{x :x}] [:x] (content x)]))
```

...which is almost OK except for two things:

1. the name app# expands to two different names
2. the ^:dynamic is missing from the result

The second is not really a problem but I am curious why does that happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gensym`s created with `#` are only reusable in the syntax quote where they were created. To reuse the generated symbol you can use an explicit call to [`gensym`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gensym) as follows:

```
(defmacro def-app [pages]
  (let [app (gensym "app")]
    `(do
       (def ~app ^:dynamic {})
       ~@(for [page# pages]
           `(def-page ~app ~page#)))))
```

This expands too:

```
(do (def app22770 {}) 
    (user/def-page app22770 [:page/not-found [{path :path}] [:path] (content path)]) 
    (user/def-page app22770 [:page/other-page [{x :x}] [:x] (content x)]))
```

Next, `^:dynamic` is missing because the reader macro `^:` is read before the macro-expansion compiler phase. Use the function [`vary-meta`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vary-meta) or `with-meta` to generate a dynamic var:

```
(defmacro def-app [pages]
  (let [app (gensym "app")]
    `(do
       (def ~(vary-meta app merge {:dynamic true}) {})
       ~@(for [page# pages]
           `(def-page ~app ~page#)))))
;; => user/app23239
```

We can see that the generated var is dynamic:

```
(meta (var app23239)) 
;; => {:dynamic true (...) }
```